# jenkins pipeline - start a pipeline job with input parameter via url

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the old freestyle project days we could simply start a build which had parameters like this:

```
    curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
  --data token=TOKEN \
  --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}]}'
```

This does not seem to work with pipeline input plugins

With pipelines i can accomplish this with two steps:

Submit a new job:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build
```

And then submit the input parameter:

```
curl -X POST -d json='{"parameter": {"name": "id", "value": "123"}}' 
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build/BUILD_NUMBER/input/INPUT_NAME/submit
```

But this looks cumbersome, plus i have to somehow retrieve the build_number after start, wait until job kicks in (pending time) and only then submit. And if there is a timeout on input, this complicates things even more.

Can i somehow do this via single API call?

Answer (score 0):

You can have parameterized pipeline jobs. It works just like parameterized freestyle jobs.
Just configure your job to be parameterized.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/21424/PARAMETERIZED%20BUILD.png

Comment: Yes, but i would like to have this purely through pipeline input (e.g. i cannot have a timeout with this parametrized parameter)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.
It works exactly like freestyle jobs. Is that not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As Timmy mentionned, parameterized pipelines jobs work just like parameterized freestyle jobs.

To trigger it you can execute the following command :

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?id=123 --data token=TOKEN
```

This is from [Parameterized Build documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).